# Sunspot/Solr Rails Filter

Tags: ruby-on-rails, solr, controller

**UPDATED**

I'm using sunspot/solr to search and filter data in my Rails 3.2 application. This is the second of two solr searches I'm performing on the "Gear" model.

My first search displays all of the gears in the view based on the query and the facets applied (A gear belongs to a user, and a user has many gears).

Now I'm probably thinking about this incorrectly (because I haven't looked at this in awhile).

Basically I'm now building a new search but this is also on the "Gear" model but it's in a different controller, different view and I'm trying to only search/filter/facet the results of the Users gears but I'm getting ALL of the gears in the database.

Getting following error...

**Called id for nil, which would mistakenly be 4 -- if you really wanted the id of nil, use object_id**

What am I missing?

**Show Action in Controller**

```
   def show
     @store = Store.find(params[:id])
     @user = @store.user
     @search2 = Gear.solr_search do
          fulltext params[:search]        
          facet (:category_name)
          facet(:sub_category_name)
          facet (:state)
          facet (:city)
          facet (:price)
          with(:user_id, @user.id)
          with(:price, params[:price]) if params[:price].present?
          with(:state, params[:state]) if params[:state].present?
          with(:city, params[:city]) if params[:city].present?
          with(:sub_category_name, params[:name]) if params[:name].present?
          with(:category_name, params[:categoryname]) if params[:categoryname].present?
          paginate(page: params[:page], :per_page => 15)
     end

     @gears = @search2.results
  end
```

I was doing this *@gears = @store.user.gears.paginate(page: params[:page])* before trying sunspot.

**Gear Model**

```
class Gear < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :title, :size, :price, :sub_category_id, :user_id, :image, :image_a, :image_b, :image_c, :image_d, :image_e, :image_f, :image_g, :image_h, :image_i, :remote_image_url, :color, :year, :latefee, :cancellation, :minrental, :policy, :about, :address, :city, :state, :zip, :country, :latitude, :longitude, :gmaps
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :sub_category

  searchable do
     text :title, :size, :price, :year, :zip, :state, :city, :minrental, :about, :latefee, :color

     text :user_firstname do
          user.firstname
     end

     text :user_lastname do
          user.lastname
     end
     # **Facet Section**   

     string :size 
     string :price
     string :state
     string :city

     string :sub_category_name , :multiple => true, :stored => true do
       sub_category.name
     end

     string :category_name, :multiple => true, :stored => true do
       category.name
     end
   end
end
```

**Store Model**

```
class Store < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :storeimage, :storename
  belongs_to :user
  mount_uploader :storeimage, StoreUploader
end
```

**User Model**

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base 

  attr_accessible :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :remember_me, :firstname, :lastname, :userimage, :remove_userimage, :name
  has_many :gears
  has_many :comments, :dependent => :destroy 
  has_one :store, :dependent => :destroy
  require 'carrierwave/orm/activerecord'
  mount_uploader :userimage, UserpicUploader
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :store


end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPDATED**

Thanks for publishing models code. Please check if this works for you now. Note `user = @store.user` assignment in controller action uses local `user` variable rather than instance variable `@user`. Don't forget to reindex your models after adding `:user_ids` to searchable fields.

```
class Gear < ActiveRecord::Base
  searchable do
    integer :user_id
  end
end

# now the controller action
def show
  @store = Store.find(params[:id])
  user = @store.user

  @search2 = Gear.solr_search do
    with(:user_id, user.id)
    # all other search code omitted for brevity
  end
end
```

Comment: I get the following error: undefined method `user' for #<Sunspot::DSL::Search:0x007f8da6b9d918>

Comment: oh, sorry, it shoud've been `@store.user` in your example. I updated the answer.

Comment: I updated it now throwing a different error: undefined method `user' for nil:NilClass

Comment: Hmm, probably it uses `instance_eval` somewhere in the implementation of `Sunspot.search`, and because of that `@store` is evaluated in the context of Sunspot instance, and not the controller action.

Comment: Try this: put `user = @store.user` right the next line after `@store = ...`, and add `with(:user_ids, user.id)` to the search conditions (without @ before user).

Comment: It gave me the same error undefined method 'user' for nil:NilClass

Comment: Sorry for bothering, but I made yet another update. :) I read your code wrong and thought that Gear `has_many :users`. But it actually `belongs_to :user`, so there is no need in indexing multiple integer user_ids.